# RichFaces modal panel not working with IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, richfaces, hide

I'm using rich:modalPanel and every time when I want to close it (I'm calling the hide method) it doesn't close.
Here is my code:

```
            <a4j:status onstart="#{rich:component('wait')}.show()" onstop="#{rich:component('wait')}.hide()"/>
            <rich:modalPanel id="wait" autosized="true" width="200" height="120" moveable="false"
                             resizeable="false" >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Processing"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="Wait Please..."/>
            </rich:modalPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is going to solve your problem but you can try the following

```
<a4j:status onstart="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('wait');" onstop="javascript:Richfaces.hideModalPanel('wait')"/>
```

This seems to work for me